# Cannot establish websocket connection using express-ws

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I'm trying to make a chatting service on express server using express-ws, but I have trouble establishing a websocket connection.

`app.js`:

```js
const app = express();
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app)
const chatRouter = require("./routes/chat")

...

app.use("/chat", chatRouter)

...

module.exports = app;
```

`routes/chat.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Welcome to chatting service!");
});

router.get('/msg', (req, res) => {
    console.log('get route');
    res.end();
});

router.ws('/msg', (ws, req) => {
    ws.on('message', msg => {
        console.log(msg);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I try to establish a websocket connection using postman, it shows error.

```
Could not connect to ws://localhost:3000/chat/msg
Error: Unexpected server response: 200

Handshake Details
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/chat/msg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
```

How can I solve this?

I've tried plugging express-ws directly into the router, like this:

`routes/chat.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(router)

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Welcome to chatting service!");
});

router.get('/msg', (req, res) => {
    console.log('get route');
    res.end();
});

router.ws('/msg', (ws, req) => {
    ws.on('message', msg => {
        console.log(msg);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

but the results were the same.